# delphi Form read error

Tags: delphi, devexpress, anydac

Yesterday i was working on a project and everything worked fine, but today when i opened Delphi XE i opened the group project file and then the necessary form and i got this error:

[image]

if i press ignore my whole project goes bad because there are some forms that needs it, if i press cancel i get:

[image]

but then then the form opens and when i try to compile the project it gives me this:

[image]

the most interesting thing is that the component files aren't located in

```
C:/erpo/121129/frxadcomponents
```

this is the directory where the group project lies, i specified the correct library and browsing paths in Delphi and i can see the compiled .Bpl files in

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0\Bpl\ directory
```

if i open the group project without opening the forms i can compile it just fine, any ideas guys?

```
IDE: Rad Studio XE
Components:
DevExpress
Fast Report 4.0
AnyDac
AnyDac Addon for FastReport **frxADComponents**
```

Comment: Maybe something is broken in your project options. Open your project options, there should be "Packages". See what is displayed for package you have troubles with (AnyDac Addon for FastReport). There should be full path to `.bpl` file with components. Is it broken?

Comment: the packages were all checked but jut to be sure i double clicked on the addon package and did the folowing:

selected Build
selected Uniinsall
selected Build
selected Install

And it fixed my problem, thou not sure for how long :) will check again tomorow. maybe this will be helpfull for someone :)

Comment: If you start a new project, can you see the components of the frxADComponents package in your palette?

Comment: yes i can, the most interesting thing is if i start a new project it run ok i can save it and then close and open again and erverything works ok, but with my main project if i close Delphi then i will have to reinstall the component before opening the main project every time, so it will not give me that error

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this helped me:

1. Open the DCLfrxAD15.dproj
2. Uniinstall It
3. Build It
4. Install it
5. Close and save it
6. Open your project
7. Work

the bigest minus that you have to do it everytime you reload Delphi.